# Reflection of a moving ball

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

We know that when a ball hits a wall at an angle alpha, it will bounce off with the same angle, just like the mirror rules. But why does it happen exactly?

Based on what theory does it happen? When I ask this questions elsewhere, I got the answer that is due to conservation of linear momentum. That explanation seems very implausible, right?

Answer (score 2):

There's two parts to this:

1. When the ball hits the wall, the wall will be tangent to the surface of the ball. Discounting friction, this means that the force between them must work in the perpendicular direction to the wall.
2. The wall is much more massive than the ball. So much more massive that practically nothing at all happens to it on impact and the ball retains all momentum.

So basically on impact we have a force acting in the perpendicular direction which due to the sheer mass difference flips the direction of the perpendicular velocity. The parallel velocity, however stays the same.

Having one of the components flip sign and the other stay the same is exactly the same as "bouncing off in the same angle".

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happens only when the coefficient of restitution is unity (or and elastic collision) . Which means the velocity of approach along the common normal is equal to the velocity of separation.
1) If your wall is horizontal for example, then in the x direction there is no impulse so you can conserve the momentum in that direction.
2) In the y direction you cannot apply conservation of momentum directly as there is an impulse due to normal reaction. So you apply equation of restitution which gives us velocity of separation equal to velocity of approach ( for a perfectly elastic collision). 
Hence you get this result.